# OnLine Video Recording/Editing in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am going to start one project(OnLine Video Recording/Editing). The idea is Presenter can record/edit a video online,

Please give me some inputs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Refer some of these projects which do similar thing

- The [RecordRTC-to-PHP](https://github.com/muaz-khan/WebRTC-Experiment/tree/master/RecordRTC/RecordRTC-to-PHP) project is a project which do some video
  recodrding and saving it in php server.
- Another project [Media Stream Recorder](https://github.com/streamproc/MediaStreamRecorder).

A web video editor which will run on php [here](http://softstribe.com/web-development/create-online-video-editing-website/)

Comment: Thanks for your inputs..